# SQL Method for Cascading Workload Based on Rank and Available Hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Recently I created an automated production scheduling tool through Excel that assigns a rank to items being produced in the same process, and then uses that rank in combination with the workload to create a schedule.

It functions exactly the way it is intended to, but due to the large amount of data and it being excel it has very slow performance, which is why I am looking to move the calculations over to SQL.

The general logic is like this:
-Always produce everything from the first day before the second day
-Always produce items from an earlier rank before items from a later rank

You can see how this plays out in the image below, where the line has 21.5 hours today, so items will be produced on day 1 until it equals 21.5, where the remainder is then carried over to day 2 and so on.

I was able to do this in excel using lengthy positional based formulas, but I am trying to think of a way to get the same result in SQL without having to rely on looking at the row above.

I am not sure how to convey something like 'Subtract from the available time production time of higher priority items produced on the same day'.

I apologize if the question is unclear, but any advice would be appreciated.

[Image of Production Hours Cascading by Priority and Day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEEVv.png)

[Example of Position-Based Fomula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAMck.png)

Comment: `sum() over (order by ... between rows preceding and current row)`??

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, I am using Microsoft SSMS

Comment: SSMS is just a client. But it most likely indicates SQL Server to be the actual DBMS.

Comment: Yes, we are using Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to shawnt00, that put me in the right direction. Ultimately I had to modify the case statements a bit to go off of the cumulative total instead, but I was able to get the desired results using a sum() Over (partition by order by ) statement.